# How to setup OpenCL on Travis CI?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, opencl, travis-ci, apt-get

I have a module on the NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nooocl. This is an OpenCL 1.1/1.2 bindings library for Node.js. I'm trying to setup Travis CI for build and unit test automation, but I haven't found a way to install OpenCL CPU libraries.

I've tried:

```
before_install:
- sudo apt-get update -qq
- sudo apt-get install -qq fglrx=2:8.960-0ubuntu1 opencl-headers
```

see .travis.yml [there](https://github.com/unbornchikken/NOOOCL/blob/master/.travis.yml)

But no luck, I get *libOpenCL.so not found* error.

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, thats why I get libOpenCL.so not found error. It's interesting, that If I see the Travis CI build log, I cannot see a trace of installing any packages. Using -qq should not disable apt-get output entirely according to this issue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/258219/how-do-i-make-apt-get-install-less-noisy